# How to get the list of unselected items in highmaps?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I can set some properties for the items that are selected in highmaps using the following property:

```
states: {
    select: {
        color: "red";
    }
}
```

How can I do the opposite? I would like to keep the colors for selected items and turn all unselected items into grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `click` event for point to change general series color. For example:

```
        series: [{
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function() {
                        if (this.state === 'hover') {
                            this.series.update({
                                color: 'gray'
                            });
                        } else {
                            this.series.update({
                                color: "#7cb5ec"
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                select: {
                    color: "red"
                }
            },
            ...
        }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/05qkz49g/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.events.click

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

---

**Edit:**

Multiple selections with shades:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'select', function(proceed, selected, accumulate) {
        accumulate = true;
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    });
}(Highcharts));


var H = Highcharts,
    minColor = '#80e3ff',
    maxColor = '#0015ff',
    minGrayColor = '#f5f5f5',
    maxGrayColor = '#545454';

// Load the data from a Google Spreadsheet
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WBx3mRqiomXk_ks1a5sEAtJGvYukguhAkcCuRDrY1L0/pubhtml
H.data({
    ...
    parsed: function(columns) {

        H.mapChart('container', {
            ...,

            series: [{
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            var series = this.series,
                                points = series.points,
                                index,
                                colorAxis = series.colorAxis;

                            function changeColor(point, gray) {
                                var pos = colorAxis.normalizedValue(point.value),
                                    minCol = gray ? minGrayColor : minColor,
                                    maxCol = gray ? maxGrayColor : maxColor;

                                point.update({
                                    color: H.color(minCol).tweenTo(H.color(maxCol), pos)
                                }, false);
                            }

                            if (!series.selectedPoints) {
                                series.selectedPoints = [];
                            }

                            if (this.state === 'hover') {
                                if (!series.changedColor) {
                                    points.forEach(function(point) {
                                        changeColor(point, true);
                                    }, this);

                                    series.changedColor = true;
                                }

                                series.selectedPoints.push(this);
                                changeColor(this);
                                series.chart.redraw();

                            } else {

                                index = series.selectedPoints.indexOf(this);
                                series.selectedPoints.splice(index, 1);
                                changeColor(this, true);

                                if (!series.selectedPoints.length) {
                                    points.forEach(function(point) {
                                        changeColor(point)
                                    }, this);

                                    series.chart.redraw();
                                    series.changedColor = false;
                                }

                                series.chart.redraw();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                ...
            }]
        });
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/juLn5skc/

Comment: Will this also handle the shades? I want the selected items to be shades of blue and unselected items to be shades of gray.

Comment: Hi @yukashima huksay, You can set any color, example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e617cyLk/

Comment: No, highmaps has this feature that the color of regions are shades of a certain color based on the data so the region with the highest number has the darkest shade etc, I want the data to determine the brightness of regions and I want the color to be determined by the selection so half of the region are shades of grey based on their data values and the other half which are the selected regions are shades of blue based on their data values.

Comment: Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/egL9kx6u/ Do you mean something like that?

Comment: I'm sorry but no. like I said. "which are the selected regions"  I don't want to only have one selected region. I want multiple selections.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. please add it to your answer.